# How can I resize my border without displacing content in the following example?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle is down so I will attach a small chunk of raw HTML below.  It is basically a small amount of content surrounded by a black border.  Currently the border is too wide.  At the moment, in bootstrap.css there is a line that is commented out

```
width: 320px;
```

This is the actual width that I want but the content is completely displaced when I uncomment this line. How do I reduce the width of the black border whilst retaining the proper layout?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/code/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        }
    </style>
    <link href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/code/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <!-- <div class="span6">&nbsp;hlo world</div> -->
    <div id="main">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span4 offset4">
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Roll The Dice &raquo;</a></p>

                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong>Don</strong> wins!!
                </div>



            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="span2 offset4">
                <h2>Don's stats</h2>

                <ul>
                    <li>Rolls: 764</li>
                    <li>Wins: 322</li>
                    <li>%: 0.532</li>
                    <li>Profit: $5297</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="span2">
                <h2>Ang's stats</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Rolls: 764</li>
                    <li>Wins: 322</li>
                    <li>%: 0.532</li>
                    <li>Profit: $5297</li>
                </ul>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the #main width and live the spanX widths intact. If you want the whole page to have a max width of 320px, then you must edit the span1,2,3,etc declarations to be each 320/12 larger than its previous (instead of 940px that is now). If, however, you only want your bordered area to be 320px wide, then you can remove the border from the #main element and place it to an inner span4 element, like this (I have put an inline red border to depict the example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/code/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        }
    </style>
    <link href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/code/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
    <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <!-- <div class="span6">&nbsp;hlo world</div> -->
    <div id="main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "span4 offset4"  style = "border:1px solid red">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Roll The Dice &raquo;</a></p>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <strong>Don</strong> wins!!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <h2>Don's stats</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rolls: 764</li>
                            <li>Wins: 322</li>
                            <li>%: 0.532</li>
                            <li>Profit: $5297</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <h2>Ang's stats</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rolls: 764</li>
                            <li>Wins: 322</li>
                            <li>%: 0.532</li>
                            <li>Profit: $5297</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```